# Livepatch not working in Ubuntu

Tags: kernel, canonical-livepatch

Signed in yesterday for Ubuntu pro.
The livepatch staus in the top bar shows a orange explanation mark on it.
When i click on it it says:

> An error occured when checking for livepatch updates.

I am running the mainline kernel:

Linux bigbeast 6.0.0-060000-generic #202210022231 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sun Oct 2 22:35:09 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[image]

Is this the reason for the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Canonical Livepatch only supports [select Ubuntu kernels](https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch/docs/kernels) (see the link for a list of supported kernels).

Since you have installed a different kernel (that is not an official Ubuntu kernel), Livepatch will not work.